# Drawing lines in 3D space

Tags: c++, directx9

When attempting to draw a line in 3D space with `D3DPT_LINELIST`, then Direct3D gives me an error about an invalid vertex declaration, saying that it cannot be converted to an `FVF`. I am using the same vertex declaration and shader/stream setup as for my `D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST` rendering which works absolutely correctly.

How can I use `D3DPT_LINELIST` to render some lines in 3D space?

Edit: Here's my raw Draw call.

```
D3DCALL(device->SetStreamSource(1, PerBoneBuffer.get(), 0, sizeof(PerInstanceData)));
D3DCALL(device->SetStreamSourceFreq(1, D3DSTREAMSOURCE_INSTANCEDATA | 1));
D3DCALL(device->SetStreamSource(0, LineVerts, 0, sizeof(D3DXVECTOR3)));
D3DCALL(device->SetStreamSourceFreq(0, D3DSTREAMSOURCE_INDEXEDDATA | lines.size()));
D3DCALL(device->SetIndices(LineIndices));
PerInstanceData* data;
std::vector<Wide::Render::Line*> lines_vec(lines.begin(), lines.end());
D3DCALL(PerBoneBuffer->Lock(0, lines.size() * sizeof(PerInstanceData), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&data), D3DLOCK_DISCARD));
std::for_each(lines.begin(), lines.end(), [&](Wide::Render::Line* ptr) {
    data->Color = D3DXColor(ptr->Colour);
    D3DXMATRIXA16 Translate, Scale, Rotate;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&Translate, ptr->Start.x, ptr->Start.y, ptr->Start.z);
    D3DXMatrixScaling(&Scale, ptr->Scale, 1, 1);
    D3DXMatrixRotationQuaternion(&Rotate, &D3DQuaternion(ptr->Rotation));
    data->World = Scale * Rotate * Translate;
});
D3DCALL(PerBoneBuffer->Unlock());
D3DCALL(device->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPRIMITIVETYPE::D3DPT_LINELIST, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1));
```

Here's my vertex declaration:

```
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 BasicMeshVertices[] = {
    {0, 0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION, 0},
    {1, 0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 0},
    {1, 16, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 1},
    {1, 32, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 2},
    {1, 48, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 3},
    {1, 64, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT4, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_COLOR, 0},
    D3DDECL_END()
};
```

The `LineIndices` are just `0, 1` and the `LineVerts` are just `{0,0,0}` and `{1,0,0}`, to represent a unit 3D line along the X axis.

Comment: Please, give us some source code ;)

Comment: @zacharmarz: Oops, my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just forgot to set the shader to the device.